# ./rcpp: No such file or directory:Run time error for cpp object file

Tags: c++, rcpp

I have tried this cpp code with Rcpp header.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// This is a simple example of exporting a C++ function to R. You can
// source this function into an R session using the Rcpp::sourceCpp 
// function (or via the Source button on the editor toolbar). 


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {
    return x * 2;
}



/*** R
timesTwo(42)
*/
```

First i have compiled like `g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include -c rcpp.cpp` . Later i used  `g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include -c rcpp.cpp  -L/usr/share/R/include -L/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include` for linking. But both creates a object file. But i need to show the output.

1. For making object file executable, i used `chmod u+x rcpp.o` command.
2. For unning ./rcpp 
   But this creates error.`bash: ./reg: No such file or directory`
   But i am compile the code from the same directory itself. Anybody know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: The object file is not executable. Try `g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include rcpp.cpp  -L/usr/share/R/include -L/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include -o rcpp`. Parameter `-c` is for compile only and creates object files. Without `-c` the compiler will compile and link in one step.

Comment: Getting some undefined references like  _reg.cpp:(.text._ZN4Rcpp10RstreambufILb0EE6xsputnEPKcl[_ZN4Rcpp10RstreambufILb0EE6xsputnEPKcl]+0x2c): undefined reference to `REprintf'
/tmp/cclCOgI4.o: In function `Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::overflow(int)':
reg.cpp:(.text._ZN4Rcpp10RstreambufILb1EE8overflowEi[_ZN4Rcpp10RstreambufILb1EE8overflowEi]+0x2b): undefined reference to `Rprintf'
/tmp/cclCOgI4.o: In function `Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::overflow(int)':
reg.cpp:(.text._ZN4Rcpp10RstreambufILb0EE8overflowEi[_ZN4Rcpp10RstreambufILb0EE8overflowEi]+0x2b): undefined reference to `REprintf'

Comment: Did you try to use `sourceCpp()` from your R script?

Comment: This same code could be run in R script. as a result will get, Rcpp::sourceCpp('Desktop/R_TENS/eg.cpp')

> timesTwo(42)
[1] 84

Comment: Functions like this are meant to be called from R! Why do you want to compile it into a stand-alone program?

Comment: C/Cpp codes could be run by visual studio,code blocks etc. I am just writing codes on gedit and compile it by gcc/g++ compiler. Then i faced the above problem regarding the object file.

Comment: I understand **what** you are doing. I do not understand **why** you are doing it. To me it looks like using a screw driver instead of a hammer for driving in nails.

Comment: I understood. But i am trying to call Some R code from Cpp program. I'm a beginner in this area. I thought like Rcpp and Rinside  will be used for this.

Comment: See my answer to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041271/how-to-call-a-r-function-from-c-with-passing-the-parameters/ Does that help you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174160/discussion-between-9113303-and-ralf-stubner).

Comment: yes, Thanks for your immediate response.

Answer (score 4):

Just re-read the very segment *you* quoted. It contains these three very important lines:

```
// This is a simple example of exporting a C++ function to R. You can
// source this function into an R session using the Rcpp::sourceCpp 
// function (or via the Source button on the editor toolbar).
```

That means *in R* you are supposed to do

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("theFileYouSave.cpp")
```

or if you displike `::` load the Rcpp package first:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("theFileYouSave.cpp")
```

or do as the comment says (if you use RStudio) and press the `source' button.

Nowhere does it suggest to hit `g++` directly.