# RInside call with arguments from R

Tags: r, rcpp, rinside

I am trying to pass arguments to an `exe` file that includes `RInside`, and that is compiled using `make`.

By taking this code inspired from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51134435/5224236)

```
#include <RInside.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // define two vectors in C++
    std::vector<double> x({1.23, 2.34, 3.45});
    std::vector<double> y({2.34, 3.45, 1.23});
    // start R
    RInside R(argc, argv);
    // define a function in R
    R.parseEvalQ("rtest <- function(x, y) {x + y}");
    // transfer the vectors to R
    R["x"] = x;
    R["y"] = y;
    // call the function in R and return the result
    std::vector<double> z = R.parseEval("rtest(x, y)");
    std::cout << z[0] << std::endl;

    // move R function to C++
    Rcpp::Function rtest((SEXP) R.parseEval("rtest"));
    // call the R function from C++
    z = Rcpp::as<std::vector<double>>(rtest(x, y));
    std::cout << z[0] << std::endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

I have two concerns:

First, trying `make -f Makefile.win soraw` give the error below. why is it not working ?

```
soraw.cpp:21:36: error: '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list
     z = Rcpp::as<std::vector<double>>(rtest(x, y));
                                    ^
```

Second, what would be the best way to pass `x` and `y` to this c++ code (after compiling into an exe) from R instead of declaring them in the c++ code? Should I use files?

---

**EDIT** this is the error when trying to comile with an additional space: `candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided`

```
z = Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> >(rtest(x, y));
```

gives

```
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:264:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const allocator_type& {aka const std::allocator<double>&}'
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:253:7: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector() [with _Tp = double; _Alloc = std::allocator<double>]
       vector()
       ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:253:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
make: *** [<builtin>: soorig] Error 1
```

---

**EDIT:** this is the error I get after modifying these lines in `Makefile.win`

Comment: Try adding an extra space:  `Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> >(rtest(x, y));`

Comment: Still getting the same error after modifying to `z = Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> >(rtest(x, y));`

Comment: Maybe assign to a variable first. Or try without that code, establishing that you can in fact build with RInside. Then sort out the smaller issues.

Comment: BTW with a newer g++ as _e.g._ g++ 8.2.0 as on Ubuntu 18.10 your code compiles fine.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer, I will update Rtools and post the results.

Comment: Still not working. But OK if it is about the compiler version... Any hint about passing arguments?

Comment: Your compiler version _on Windows_ is fixed.  You need to sort out why it fails.  As for passing arguments, that is the _standard problem of passing command-line arguments to C programs_.  There are answers, but that has nothing to do with Rcpp or RInside.

Comment: Can you update code and error message to the version with the added space for the nested template arguments.

Comment: Sure ralf, will do this evening. In the meantime, would you have hints on how to pass these vectors as arguments?

Comment: Done @RalfStubner , please see edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with compilation seems to be that Dirk's and my `g++` default to C++11, while the one from Rtools does not. You can fix that by changing the way `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` are defined in the `GNUmakefile` that comes with `RInside`:

```
CXX :=      $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXX11) $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXX11STD)
CPPFLAGS := -Wall $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CPPFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS := $(RCPPFLAGS) $(RCPPINCL) $(RINSIDEINCL) $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXX11FLAGS)
```

Alternatively you could remove all the niceties from C++11.

As for how to provide the input data: That really depends whether you want to provide possibly long vectors or not. I would use files for the former case.

Comment: Thanks Ralf, will check that this evening

Comment: Just tried to replace these lines in the Makefile.win - as I am on windows and I get this error `g++.exe: error: =: No such file or directory
make: *** [<builtin>: soorig] Error 1`

Comment: Changing these lines in GNUmakefile gives another error however: 
`note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const allocator_type& {aka const std::allocator<double>&}'`

Comment: next lines : `C:/Rtools/mingw_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:253:7: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector() [with _Tp = double; _Alloc = std::allocator<double>]
       vector()
       ^`

Comment: @gpier Please add the `Makefile.win` as well as the error messages you see to the question. Comments are insufficient for such information.

Comment: must have made a wrong manipulation. it now works using Makefile.win modified as per your suggestion. Many thanks